# Is there a place to see release dates for previous releases?

Tags: release

I have some production functionality that has recently stopped working and I am looking for "proof" that it happened due to the winter '15 release.

Is there any place where the release dates for past release (such as  the winter 15) are still available?

They are no longer under scheduled maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is strictly authoritative, but a few slides in, it shows the roadmap and I believe the schedule was adhered to:
http://www.slideshare.net/RoyGilad/salesforce-winter-15-release-overview

Are you just trying to confirm the date that it was rolled out?

Comment: Thanks!

Yes, just want to confirm the dates. I never really thought about this before but it's very odd that this information isn't available.

Comment: Yeah,  I recall having to track down something like this before and having to find someone's presentation or speaking notes.

Comment: I've also used archive.org Wayback Machine snaps of trust.salesforce.com.

Answer (score 3):

Search for `"Season YY" site:blogs.salesforce.com`

For example, `"Winter 14" site:blogs.salesforce.com`

---

Here are the dates for EU1 for the past couple of years.

```
Winter ’15 - 17 Oct 2014
Summer ’14 - 18 Jul 2014 – delayed release
Spring ’14 - 18 Apr 2014 – delayed release
Winter ’14 - 12 Oct 2013
Summer ’13 - 15 Jun 2013
Spring ’13 - 09 Feb 2013
```

---

Or as one of the comments says, you can use archive.org.

Comment: [Where to find historical release dates?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54993/where-to-find-historical-release-dates)

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a bit unorthadox, but it came up when answering the twitter question:

> How do I see when Winter '16 was released for my org (na16)?  The calendar on Trust goes back only to March #askforce
>   [Krystal D Carter](https://twitter.com/kdcSFDClifer/status/725083685414920193)

I found that the [RSS feed from the trust site](http://trust.salesforce.com/rest/rss/NA16) included details about the release, but only went back a limited number of days.

So I jumped over to the [web archive and looked for snapshots around the suspected date](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515000000*/http://trust.salesforce.com/rest/rss/NA16).

I found that Winter '16 went live on na16 17th Oct 2015 [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20151020184011/https://trust.salesforce.com/rest/rss/NA16).

Answer (score 0):

Only back to Spring 2013

Release     1st Date

---

Summer '21 - 05 Jun 2021

Spring '21 - 16 Jan 2021

Winter '21 - 18 Sep 2020

Summer '20 - 12 Jun 2020

Spring '20 - 10 Jan 2020

Winter '20 - 20 Sep 2019

Summer '19 - 18 May 2019

Spring '19 - 02 Feb 2019

Winter '19 - 15 Sep 2018

Summer '18 - 11 Jun 2018

Spring '18 - 12 Apr 2018

Winter '18 - 14 Oct 2017

Summer '17 - 09 Jun 2017

Spring '17 - 07 Mar 2017

Winter '17 - 08 Oct 2016

Summer '16 - 20 May 2016

Spring '16 - 15 Jan 2016

Winter '16 - 17 Oct 2015 (25 Sep)

Summer '15 - 22 May 2015

Spring '15 - 16 Jan 2015

Winter ’15 - 17 Oct 2014

Summer ’14 - 18 Jul 2014 – delayed release

Spring ’14 - 18 Apr 2014 – delayed release

Winter ’14 - 12 Oct 2013

Summer ’13 - 15 Jun 2013

Spring ’13 - 09 Feb 2013