# Where to find historical release dates?

Tags: administration, release

Is there any place on the internet which lists the historical release dates for Winter, Spring and Summer, for every year and every Salesforce instance?

Comment: Thanks @Girbot. However, that question is only regarding one particular release. Is there any place to see the entire list of historical release dates?

Comment: The comments on that question suggest there isn't a dedicated list anywhere but the last comment might be able to help: "I've also used archive.org Wayback Machine snaps of trust.salesforce.com"

Comment: Would you mind also adding your answer to the other question ? Ive updated it to be more generic.

Comment: Sure @SamuelDeRycke. I'll add the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `"Season YY" site:blogs.salesforce.com`

For example, `"Winter 14" site:blogs.salesforce.com`

---

Here are the dates for EU1 for the past couple of years.

```
Winter ’15 - 17 Oct 2014
Summer ’14 - 18 Jul 2014 – delayed release
Spring ’14 - 18 Apr 2014 – delayed release
Winter ’14 - 12 Oct 2013
Summer ’13 - 15 Jun 2013
Spring ’13 - 09 Feb 2013
```

Comment: If you can find the historical dates maybe it's worth adding them all to the answer and making a community wiki out of it?

Comment: Brilliant idea @Girbot. I'll do that in the weekend!